# In Node-Red, how to execute a script with arguments but not wait for completion?

Tags: node-red

I want to message a telegram bot a code which is used as an argument for a python script. Problem is, the script does a sleep function until the day/time it needs to run.

Is it possible to run a script without waiting for completion; sending it to the background so that node-red can execute another instance of the script when it gets a new code from telegram?

I tried the daemon node but it doesn't have a feature to add arguments from the payload, unless I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Exec' node can be configured to output messages while the command is still running - known as 'spawn mode'. Just take note of the tip in the Exec node's sidebar help:

> Tip: if running a Python app you may need to use the -u parameter to stop the output being buffered.

Comment: Will that allow another instance to be run before the first finishes?